# Dynamic slideshow in jQuery + Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, slideshow

I am trying to work with any simple jQuery slideshow in which the images and text will come dynamically.

The Rails code is like this:

```
.section
    -@testimonials.each do |testimonial|
        .section
            .row.testimonial.round
                .three.columns
                    =image_tag(testimonial.testifier.thumb_small.url)           
                .eight.columns.testimonial-description
                    .row.testimonial-description
                        %blockquote
                            %span(class = "bqstart") &#8220
                            =testimonial.description 
                            %span(class = "bqend") &#8221
                    .row.testifier-details
                        %strong="#{testimonial.name}  #{testimonial.designation} #{testimonial.company}"
                .one.columns
```

This will give me the image and description from the database.

If I want to put these results in a slideshow, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing never worked with Zurb Orbit (slideshow). I switched to slide.js which is a much better slideshow IMO and it worked.

After installing slides.js in the `ass/assets/javascript`this is the html for the slideshow :-

```
.section
    #testimonial-slideshow.round
        -@testimonials.each do |testimonial|
            .row
                .three.columns
                    =image_tag(testimonial.testifier.thumb_small.url)           
                .nine.columns
                    .row.testimonial-description

                        %span(class = "bqstart") &#8220
                        =truncate(testimonial.description, :length => 150)  
                        %span(class = "bqend") &#8221
                    .row.testimonial-name
                        %strong="#{testimonial.name}  #{testimonial.designation} #{testimonial.company}"
```

and the js looks like this :-

```
$('#testimonial-slideshow').slides({
            width: 600,
            height: 120,
            generateNextPrev: false,
            pagination: false,
            play: 1000
    });
```